# Login with Facebook publish_stream

Tags: facebook, authentication

When I create a button with the following code, it does not ask for permissions to **publish_stream**. What is wrong with the code?

```
  <div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins,publish_stream">
    Login with Facebook
  </div>
```

Here is the full code; (ps: it doesn't work unless it's hosted on localhost). http://jsfiddle.net/xCTCh

Comment: may be you had already authorized?

Comment: Nope, I removed all authorization from my account. Here is the full code; (ps: it doesn't work unless it's hosted on localhost). http://jsfiddle.net/xCTCh/

Comment: since publish_stream is a extended permission it would ask you in another window after first approved app.. 

otherwise try using FB.login java script function

Comment: Will do! Thanks. I'm guessing after authenticating with JS, I can post to wall with PHP?